# perform multiple DOM changes at once

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

My frontend framework is very asynchronous. It means, that when the user exetutes some action, then the "model" is changed and after that a bunch of callbacks modifying the DOM are called. Changes of the "model" and dependent callbacks are called asynchronously, because some data has to be "consulted" with server.  It leads to ugly reflows.

I've experimented and if I make multiple DOM changes in one code block using JQuery, all is done at once, but my ramework needs it to be done asynchronously in independent calls.

What I need is something like transactions in DB world. Before I start to code some batch DOM update library, I want to know if there is not simpler way.

In my case, all changed elements have one parent, so I wish I could tell the browser: "Do not redraw children of this node. Make different changes to all children. Now redraw all children of this node". Can you help me?

Comment: What frontend framework are you currently using?

Comment: none, I'm creating my own one which uses just JQuery lib. I need it lightweight.

Comment: This sounds like you just want to make changes on a DocumentFragment (or other detached DOM element) and then swap it in place when the edits are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe **there's no API to tell the browser to pause reflow/restyle/rendering** so that it doesn't repaint after you returned control to the event loop and are waiting for additional data from the server.

It's hard to present a proof that something doesn't exist, but I think the fact that the HTML spec's ["Processing model"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) doesn't mention anything like this -- only heuristics like *"user agent might wish to spend less resources rendering third-party content, especially if it is not currently visible to the user"* -- is telling.

Another thought: how would the browser handle [API calls that ask for layout/style information](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) on elements that have their rendering paused? Return the stale information corresponding to the last rendering? What about the newly created elements?

---

I'm posting this answer because you said the focus of this question was about built-in browser support, but I think
[charlietfl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192803/1026) is the right solution for the problem given how browsers work.

Answer (score 1):

Use promises and do all the dom manipulation after all promises have resolved. Note that `$.ajax` returns a promise and you can chain multiple ajax calls by returning each in a `then()` and then finally return what is needed to do the dom manipulation once all of the request promises have resolved

```
function doStuff() {
  return $.post('/echo/json/', {json: '{"item":1}'}).then(data => {
    // return function we can call when all requests completed
    return function() {
      console.log('doStuff() data', data)
    }
  })
}

function doOtherStuff() {
   return $.post('/echo/json/', {json: '{"item":22}'}).then(data => {
    // return function we can call when all requests completed
    return function() {
      console.log('doOtherStuff() data', data)
    }
  })
}



Promise.all([doStuff(), doOtherStuff()]).then(function(funcs) {
  // now all requests complete call each of the returned functions
  funcs.forEach(f => f())
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wfvjvv67/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes, but I cannot detect that all changes were made. I'm thinking about batch processing of queued DOM updates and I will use promises in it, because I love them :-). But I'm asking if there is not browser support of "stop updating DOM, make nodes updates, now update DOM"

Comment: This approach would batch updates together. Would need to look for an observable library probably to do what you are asking

Comment: Or use a more robust framework like vue, angular, react etc. jQuery is simply a library but isn't well suited for what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the idea of ReactJS. ReactJS has something call virtual DOM (Javascript object) which manages to minimize HTML DOM manipulation.

Learn more about ReactJS https://reactjs.org/

Comment: I know about ReactJS, but I don't like the idea of JSX and babel and .... No flame, I honestly respect ReactJS. I need some lightweight solution for my project. Do you know about any virtual DOM lib, which renders at one time two modifications of two nodes performed 300ms apart? Something which can do "begin update" .... "commit" thing.

Comment: As you described in you question, I don't know a framework that can fit your need. About reactjs, I had the same feeling as you originally but after giving it a try, I can tell it's great framework that saves your development time and produces high performance web app. Plus, if you know reactjs, you're one step closer to React Native, which is a great framework for building mobile application